# How to pass parametrs to scheduled apex class?

Tags: apex, case, scheduled-apex

I have a method where I need to schedule an apex class that will close several Cases in 5 days but I need to somehow pass Case Id so the scheduled class knows which cases to remove after 5 days. How to do it?

Now schedule method looks like this but CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable is empty

```
public static void scheduleCloseCaseJob(List<Case> cases, Map<Id, Case> oldCases) {
    for (Case c : cases) {
        if (c.Status == 'Waiting for customer reply' || c.Status == 'Waiting for customer approval') {
            String day = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().addDays(20).day());
            String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
            String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute()); 
            String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());

            //parse to cron expression
            String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day +' * ?';
            System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, nextFireTime, new CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not set a flag on the Case, then the scheduled class queries based on that flag for which records to process?

Comment: Because Case Priority Flag is already used for another feature

Comment: So create a new custom field?

Comment: But there can be many Scheduled Jobs at one time. Is it okay to create many custom fields?

Comment: Why are you using APEX for this (as you seem to be relatively inexperienced with that technology)? Couldn't it be resolved by a Flow or time-based workflow?